# Separar un arreglo para que cada elemento se tome como una opción en un componente Select de react

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, select

Buen día a todos.

Estoy trabajando en un webmap con react leaflet. Tengo una capa en geojson llamada "localidades" que me arroja un arreglo los nombres de las localidades.

El problema es que necesito que cada nombre se tome como una **opción diferente** en un componente Select que hice, pero hasta ahora solamente me imprime un arreglo con todos los nombres de localidades en una sola opción:

1. Guanajuato Tlaxcala Sonora Chiapas

Cuando deberían ser tomados como opciones separadas:

1. Guanajuato
2. Tlaxcala
3. Sonora
4. Chiapas

Podría hacerlo manualmente, es decir, escribir todas las opciones por separado pero el problema es que la capa tiene alrededor de 500 elementos y tendría que hacer esas 500 opciones para mi Select. Además de que lo voy a repetir con otras capas.

Hay alguna manera de separarlo y que tome cada elemento como una opción de mi Select de una forma sencilla?

```
const opcLugar = useMemo((idCapa,idFeature) => {
    let capa = undefined;
    capasRBAC.forEach((item) => {
      if (idCapa == item.id) {
        capa = item;
      }
    });
    let feature = capa.capa.features[idFeature];
    setFeatureEditable(feature);

    if (valueFiltrarCapa === 'Localidades') {
      let nombreLocalidad=[];
      for(var i=0;i<=(capaLocNom.features.length)-1;i++){
      nombreLocalidad[i]=capaLocNom.features[i].properties.NOMGEO;          
    }
      return[{name:nombreLocalidad}];
      
    }
    if (valueFiltrarCapa === 'Colonias') {
      return [{ name: 'Aquí ocupo otras opciones con nombres de colonia' }];
    }
    if (valueFiltrarCapa === 'Calles') {
      return [{ name: 'Aquí ocupo otras opciones con nombres de calles' }];
    }

    return [];
  }, [valueFiltrarCapa]);
```

Soy relativamente nuevo programando así que aún hay varias cosas que no entiendo. Les agradezco mucho su tiempo y su ayuda :)

Comment: En que parte pasas el valor al select? podrías mostrar lo que te llega en el JSON? podrías mostrar de que forma se lo tienes que pasar al select si se lo pasaras manualmente?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día. Ya lo solucioné.

Cree la variable arregloLoc vacía y fui haciendo un .push() con cada dato nuevo para ir acomodándolos de la forma que mi select lo necesitaba ({name:nombreLocalidad}).
Al final, solo retorné la nueva variable arregloLoc ya sin corchetes ni llaves porque ya estaba acomodada con el formato que deseaba. Gracias a todos los que leyeron mi pregunta :)

```
if (valueFiltrarCapa === 'Localidades') {
      let nombreLocalidad=[];
      let arregloLoc=[];
        for(var i=0;i<=(capaLocNom.features.length)-1;i++){
        nombreLocalidad[i]=capaLocNom.features[i].properties.NOMGEO;
        arregloLoc.push({name:nombreLocalidad[i]});
        }
      return arregloLoc;
```